# Why is a single insert statement, originating two rows instead of a single row?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I need to insert data from a webform into a SQL Server table. But for some reason, each time the fields and dropdown lists in the web form are filled and the insert button is clicked, two rows with almost the same data are inserted, only sucursal changes. Besides the `id_veiculo` which is the table's primary key is auto incremental, I have an index on the `Matricula` column so this shouldn't be possible with repeated values.

I've deleted all records and tried to insert a new record but the problem remains.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
        //configuração da instrução de inserção 
        Command.Connection = C;
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO veiculo (id_sucursal, matricula, data_matricula, id_marca, id_modelo, id_estado, id_seguro, id_estacionamento, numero_frota) VALUES(@Id_sucursal, @Matricula, @DtMatricula, @Id_marca, @Id_modelo, @Id_estado, NULL, NULL, @NumFrota)";

        //leitura dos valores definidos 
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_sucursal", DropDownSucursais.SelectedValue);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Matricula", txtMatricula.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DtMatricula", CalendarMatricula.SelectedDate);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_marca", DropDownMarcas1.SelectedValue);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_modelo", DropDownModelos2.SelectedValue);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_estado",DropDownEstados1.SelectedValue);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumFrota",txtNumFrota.Text);

        //execução da instrução sobre a base de dados 
        try
        {
            C.Open();
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (C.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                C.Close();
        }

        //actualizar GridView e limpar os campos 
        SelectVeiculos();
        cleanFields();
}
```

I expect to see a single row appended per insert.

Comment: [Please stop using `AddWithValue()`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Also why aren't you using `Using` blocks for your connection / command?

Comment: _"I expect to see a single row appended per insert."_ And I guess it surely does. If you really observe two rows, there must be a reason why the code is executed twice. Maybe you registered the event handler twice or something like that.

Comment: How are you looking at the data? Make sure when you look at data you use Order By.  Inserting and Select returns data randomly since the SQL Data Base is multi-threaded.  the code shouldn't be adding the same data twice so probably the old data was in the database but you didn't see the data when you did a query.

Comment: Does your table have a trigger?

Comment: You get sucursal from a dropdown on a form. So if it would be something wrong with the code you`ve presented it won't change. The change means, that you have an error somwhere else in the code, than calls this method, It is possible, that it is attached to some other event.

Comment: "two rows with almost the same data are inserted"...  Seems to me if you look for how the data is different you might discover that an event is triggered on the drop down where data is different at.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll try to look into the matters, you've highlighted. And the table has no trigger.

Comment: Once again, thank you for all the support. After further investigation it was detected the issue had to do with with the select statement used to feed the gridview, it had a cross join.